# HTTP request was forbidden by the client authentication scheme 'Anonymous

Tags: c#, wcf, security, client, wshttpbinding

I was digging a lot in stackoverflow.com to find answer for error: "HTTP request was forbidden by the client authentication scheme 'Anonymous", but none of proposed solutions solves my problem. So I decided to show my config files and ask about help.

I have WCF web service secured with SSL. All is fine until I started editin my WinForms Client which throws all the time error: "HTTP request was forbidden by the client authentication scheme 'Anonymous".

This is my WCF web service configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MBServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviors">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="SkillsAndTasks.CustomValidator, SkillsAndTasks"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="MBServiceBinding" />
</protocolMapping>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviors" name="SkillsAndTasks.MBService">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SkillsAndTasks.IMBService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
```

And this is my WinForms App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<applicationSettings>
    <SkillsAndTasksDesktopClient.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="MBService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>https://127.0.0.1/MBService.svc</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="MBServiceLogin" serializeAs="String">
            <value>ws1349</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="MBServicePassword" serializeAs="String">
            <value>qqlka123</value>
        </setting>
    </SkillsAndTasksDesktopClient.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMBService" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1/MBService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMBService" contract="MBService.IMBService"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IMBService">

        </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Certainly I can preview web service in browser. I have binded my site with self-signed certificate (https) too.

I suspect that it must be something with security settings...

Comment: I've seen errors similar to this before - I enabled anonymous authentication in IIS and that solved the problem, but this was with services that weren't using SSL.

Comment: Anonymous authentication is enabled but it doesn't change anything. It's rather something with WCF authentication.